# Unable to select Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, layers, select

I am using the following [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html), to select a vector layer feature on click. The example demonstrates Highlighting and selecting the layer. I was able to successfully implement the Highlighting of the layer but I am not able to select the layer.

This is my code

```
var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([vector_layer,QuebecSpecies], {
                hover: true,
                highlightOnly: true,
                renderIntent: "temporary",
                eventListeners: {
                    beforefeaturehighlighted: report,
                    featurehighlighted: report,
                    featureunhighlighted: report
                }
            });

            var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([vector_layer],
                {clickout: true}
            );

map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
map.addControl(selectCtrl);

highlightCtrl.activate();
selectCtrl.activate();
```

Where am I falling short?

Comment: did you activate it?

Comment: Its not because 'highlightOnly' is set to true is it? From the OpenLayers Manual 'If true do not actually select features (that is place them in the layer’s selected features array), just highlight them.' I've never used this particular control before so I'm just taking a stab in the dark.

Comment: Ya I did Activate it, forgot to paste that portion of the code earlier

Comment: I think it would be better to add your code in jsfiddle so we can easily help you.

Comment: Here is it http://jsfiddle.net/smaran/qTFEa/1/, the running application is [here](http://niles.iplantcollaborative.org/demo/geo/test/map.html).

Comment: Does it work if you remove the QuebecSpecies layer from the first control?

Comment: Nope it is the same.

Comment: I've done this with the following code but its worked for me,  `var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(pointLayer, {
                hover: true,
                highlightOnly: true,               
                renderIntent: "temporary"
            });
            var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([pointLayer],
                { clickout: true }
            );` I think the problem is highlightCtrl has an array of layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this i hope this will help you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TtfDe/)

This demo will display a point on a map and highlight it on mouse over and selecting point on  click will display a popup, and removes the popup on unselect

Here is the code for function :

```
function init() {
        var Geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var Mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
            minResolution: "auto",
            minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
            maxResolution: "auto",
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90),
            projection: Mercator,
            displayProjection: Geographic
        });

        var baselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(baselayer);
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(77.79, 22.77),4);
        // creates a point layer with a temporary style
        var pointLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "temporary": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    strokeColor: '#7f0000',
                    fillColor: '#7f0000',
                    strokeOpacity: .8,
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    fillOpacity: .3,
                    cursor: "default",
                    pointRadius: 6
                })
            })
        });
        // add a point to pointLayer
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(77.79, 22.77));
        pointLayer.addFeatures(feature);
        // point layer events on featureselected adds a popup and removes it on featureunselected
        pointLayer.events.on({
            featureselected: function (e) {
                latitude = e.feature.geometry.x;
                longitude = e.feature.geometry.y;
                id = e.feature.id;
                popup = new OpenLayers.Popup(id,
                            new OpenLayers.LonLat(latitude, longitude),
                            new OpenLayers.Size(200, 20),
                            id, true);
                map.addPopup(popup);
            },
            featureunselected: function (e) {
                var id = e.feature.id;
                for (var i = 0; i < map.popups.length; i++) {
                    if (map.popups[i].id == id) {
                        var x = map.popups[i];
                        map.removePopup(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        map.addLayer(pointLayer);
        // highlightControl adds the temporary style on select
        var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(pointLayer, {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            renderIntent: "temporary"
        });
        // selectControl will select a particular feature
        var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([pointLayer],
            { clickout: true }
        );

        map.addControl(highlightControl);
        highlightControl.activate();
        map.addControl(selectControl);
        selectControl.activate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to activate and add the control in right order, begin with the hover activate and add then the select event snippet.